# Group all from and to messages per user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am working on a Private Message center which will make users able to send PM's to each other through front end. The inboxes are working perfectly fine, however I would like to add a page where you are able to click on a users name and then you can see all messages send to and from with this user and the current logged in user.

For example:

**User 1**
    Message A
    Message B
    Message C
    Message D
    
    **User 2**
    Message A
    Message B
    Message C
    
    **User 3**
    Message A
    Message B
    Message C
    Message D
    Message E

In my database I have a table with all users:

```
id | user_login | user_pass | user_nicename | user_email | user_url | user_registered | user_activation_key
```

And I have a table with info of the messages:

```
id | parent_id | from_user | to_user | send_date | last_date | message_title | message_contents | status | to_del | from_del
```

The user id in table 1 corresponds with parent_id (nested messages in form of replies) and the from_user and to_user in table 2.

With the next query (which I used after I found the basis here on Stackoverflow), I am able to echo the results from the from_user column, however I would like to echo all messages send from and to a user:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT table1.id, table1.user_nicename, table2.id,
table2.from_user, table2.message_title FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.from_user 
GROUP BY user_nicename"  ); 

foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row->user_nicename." <br>  ".$row->message_title."<br>";
}
?>
```

Could anyone perhaps shed a light on it and point me into the right direction? I think I need to use something like INNER JOIN to add the to_user to the query, however I get a bit lost in it.

In case you need more information, just let me know. First time turning for help here, so I don't know if I have provided enough info :)

Thank you very much in advance for your attention and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_nicename, t2.id, t2.from_user, t2.message_title 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id IN (t2.from_user, t2.to_user)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

If you want messages of specific user then use below query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_nicename, t2.id, t2.from_user, t2.message_title 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id IN (t2.from_user, t2.to_user)
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is working! I am gonna fiddle a bit with it the upcoming days to see if I can implement it further in the page. I am actually trying to have an overview of the users and when you click on a user name you will get an overview of all the messages between the logged in user and the user he/she clicked on. Oh and Happy New Year! :D

Comment: Hi Saharsh, I have been fiddling around with your code. It is working, however I am still struggling a bit to get the outcome of the results in the way I want it :) 

When I use your code and then do the foreach{} I have mentioned in my code above, I get for each message title a the username (so username + message title, username + message title etc) instead of: username and all the messages that belong to that message (as in: username + message title + message title + message title etc. Any idea how I could accomplish this? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use group_concat function for doing so.

```
Select table1.id, table1.user_nicename, 
       group_concat(table2.message_title SEPARATOR "|") as Message
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id=table2.parent_id 
GROUP BY table2.parent_id
```

You will have the different messages concated by | 
Use PHP array explode to separate the messages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply! I haven't gotten it to work yet, but it makes sense what you are suggesting :) I am gonna fiddle with it these days! Happy New Year btw!

Comment: Thank you !! Happy new year to u too !!